# Visual Workflow Text Area Character Counter

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, flow, visual-flows

I've successfully implemented a character counter using js in a visualforce page.

I was hoping to use the same or similar functionality for text area fields in a flow embedded in a visualforce page, but can't seem to have any success.

I have implemented a validation on the flow field that limits to 255 that works fine. But I thought it'd be useful to let users know how much text they've entered vs. how much is allowed.

When I tried to put a formula... **LEN({!field_name})** ...in the validation error message, the formula gave me zero. (There's clearly hundreds of characters in the field.)

Any help on a character counter for FLOW text area fields? Or even a decent workaround?

PS. I know very little about development, but enough to be dangerous.

Comment: Is your flow embedded in a Visualforce page?

Comment: @cricketlang Yes it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply on this. I've been super swamped at work.

The answer here is yes, Flows simply have a slightly different id than other input fields, but that's super easy to find if you just inspect the element in the browser.

I have no idea what library you use to count characters, but there is a generic one that i just used to test this available [here](http://www.forcetree.com/2013/02/character-count-limit-for-inputtextarea.html).

To start, we need to find out what the field Id is by inspecting the rendered field in the browser. Here you can see my field ends with `Requester_First_Name.input` so I'll use that to select my field with jquery like so: `$("[id$=Requester_First_Name.input]")`

[image]

Now i just have to throw in the library as a Static Resource, import it into the visualforce page wrapping the Flow, configure it how you want, and enjoy the results! If you use the library I referenced, you can see some additional options you can set as desired, but here i just set a max and warning.

Let us know how it goes!

[image]

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.charCounter)}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){


        $("[id$=Requester_First_Name.input]").jqEasyCounter({
            'maxChars': 10,
            'maxCharsWarning': 5
        });


});
</script>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I had actually already put the counter in my org but couldn't figure out how to use it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @BeckBeck Did you just ping me on another counter question? I saw a notification come through but i cant find it anymore.